# Drupal Discontinued Products

Tags: drupal

I have a client that has an e-commerce site using Drupal 6.16.

When they discontinue a product, they change the product to unpublished which then returns a 403 error for the average user and Google.  This obviously isn't the best option for SEO.

What have people done in similar situations?  I was thinking of using the CustomError module to redirect them to a category page or similar, but that effects all 403's on the site and briefly stopped access to the admin of the site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best would likely to keep the products published, disabled buying (depending on the e-commerce module/solution) and update the description with reference to a replacement product and/or information about the discontinuation. This way existing links to the discontinued products will still work, and link to relevant and precise information. Which is the best SEO you could have.